# Plot categorical labels on the right, not on the left

Tags: r, plot

Suppose we start with this plot:

[image]

```
xs = table(mtcars$gear)
barplot(xs, horiz=T, yaxt="n")
```

Let's move the y labels to the right. (In the future I will place a second plot to the left, and it will share the y axis.)

[image]

```
barplot(xs, horiz=T, yaxt="n")
axis(side=4, labels=c("3","4","5"), at=c(0.5,2,3.5))
```

I have three questions:

1. How can I position the labels correctly? Right now they misaligned.
2. How can I remove the axis line and axis tick marks?
3. How can I rotate the labels 90 degrees clockwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
xx = barplot(xs, horiz=T, yaxt="n")
axis(side=4, labels=names(xs), at=xx[,1], las=1, lty=0)
```